Synapse Vs code Plugin Integration Issue
I have intalled Visual Studio code and Synapse Vs code extension, when i go to command pallet to type Synapse:Sign in then after all the configuration a pop up window opens up to sign in to Fabric. The problem is that the url which it shows when i click on Sign in is pointing to localhost and some random port. I believe the Sign in button should point to Microsoft fabric lgin url. What do i need to do to acheive that. Also i see that some fabric kerels are created. How do i select them?
I expect that when Synapse:Sign In is called then i should be asked to log into my fabric account not some localhost url

Please paste the exact Error

There is no error that I can see. i see that "Synapse:Sign in" in command pallete directs me to localhost . I expect that it should direct me to apps.microsoft.fabric

Its not that way. When you click ctrl>>Shift>>P,then it will load the workspaces from Fabric to select.You have to select from the drop down your respective Workspace
